# Getting StackOverFlow Error in Kettle(PDI)

Tags: java, kettle

everyone,when i use kettle to do loop,the error occured,the kettle's memory is 8G ，I used hundreds of cycles，Kettle to cycle 1500 times, when the cycle time to about 700 times the error occourd.how can i solve it

```
ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : java.lang.StackOverflowError
   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
   at java.io.File.exists(File.java:772)
   at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1057)
   at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1024)
   at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:172)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:551)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:549)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:548)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1138)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:227)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.createObject(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:553)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:515)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:501)
   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2797)
   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2774)
   at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.<init>(TransMeta.java:2759)
   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.getTransMeta(JobEntryTrans.java:1166)
   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.execute(JobEntryTrans.java:634)
   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:678)
   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:815)
   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:815)
   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:815)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert in Kettle.  However, a `StackOverflowError` is NOT caused by running out of memory, so the fact that you have an 8Gb heap is not directly relevant.  What is relevant is the size of the thread stack.  That is controlled by the `java` command's `-Xss` command-line option.

I also don't know what you mean by "cycles" in the context of Kettle ... and Google isn't helping me.  However, I guess it is something to do with Jobs that cause other Jobs to run.  And since you hit the limit at ~700 and need to get to ~1500, you probably need to triple the current thread stack size ... whatever that may be.

Comment: Sorry,my english is bad;
Thank you very much! Your answer is correct, it solved my question